# WPF scrollbar does not show in another monitor with different scale

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF app. The issue is when I drag the app from one monitor to another which has larger scale, it's supposed to show the scrollbar but it didn't. The issue only appears when the app starts at the screen with low scale and dragged to higher scale. However, it works fine with the opposite case (drag from higher scale to lower scale monitor).
How can I fix this?

This is the first monitor screen. Everything looks good:

[image]

Second monitor. Scrollbar does not show:
[image]

Xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class=""   
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="Window1_MouseUp"
    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
    RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    Top="0"
    UseLayoutRounding="True"
    WindowStyle="None"
    WindowState="Normal"
    ResizeMode="CanResize"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome
            CaptionHeight="0"
            CornerRadius="0"
            GlassFrameThickness="8" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

     <ScrollViewer
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
           <Grid Margin="18" VerticalAlignment="Top"> 
            // login form
           </Grid>
     </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;

     }

     private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
     {
         //DragMove();

         if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
         {
             // this prevents win7 aerosnap
             if (this.ResizeMode != System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize)
             {
                 this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
                 this.UpdateLayout();
             }

             DragMove();
         }

     }

     void Window1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
     {
         if (this.ResizeMode == System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize)
         {
             this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanResize;
             this.UpdateLayout();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Could you listen to `SizeChanged` event to test if dragging to higher DPI screen change its size? Otherwise scrollviewer might not know to show the scrollbar itself.